# The DialogPreference in android.support.v7 cause override nothing error

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code  A works well, but I get error when I replace `import android.preference.DialogPreference` with `import android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference`

why?

**Error**

```
onCreateDialogView() override nothing
onDialogClosed() override nothing
showDialog() override nothing
```

**Code A**

```
import android.preference.DialogPreference
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import info.dodata.mirror.R
import android.widget.EditText
import org.jetbrains.anko.*
import utility.PreferenceTool

class DialogChangePassword(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : DialogPreference(context, attrs) {

    private lateinit var mView: View
    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    init {
        dialogLayoutResource = R.layout.item_custom_password_dialog
    }

    override fun onCreateDialogView(): View {
        mView = super.onCreateDialogView()
        mContext=mView.context
        return mView
    }

    override fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult)
    }

    override fun showDialog(state: Bundle?) {
        super.showDialog(state)

        val d = dialog as AlertDialog
        d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {           
               d.dismiss()           
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation.

```
onCreateDialogView() override nothing
onDialogClosed() override nothing
showDialog() override nothing
```

Those method are protected/open in `android.preference.DialogPreference` (#https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference) but there is no methods like those in `android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference` (#https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/DialogPreference).

Those classes are not the same, they don't have the same public interface. That's why.

Comment: It's depends what are you going to do, but you have to use proper class. There is a reason why those class are not the same. I've found some example here: https://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/